# Ensuring emails are lower case when searching/inserting/updating MySQL database with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, lowercase

I am using PHP's PDO to interact with a MySQL database. I am currently using the following code to ensure an email address is always lower case to make sure there are no duplicates when inserting/updating or to find an email when searching.

Can someone tell me if this is okay the way it is or is it better to use the SQL or PHP way of converting to lower case?

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET name=:name, LOWER(email)=:email WHERE id = :id";
$st->bindValue(":email", strtolower($this->email), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: i see nothing wrong with this (besides me always using UPPER() for no particular reason for the same kind of problem ;-) )

Comment: If you choose to go with the SQL versions, this is correct:
`$sql = "UPDATE table SET name=:name, email = LOWER(:email) WHERE id = :id";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write to `LOWER(email)` and it's also unnecessary since you are always inserting the lower-cased version via PHP anyway.  Just change it to `email`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to always prep you data before you enter it into a database. So in otherwords do all of the case changing in php.

In this case you can use:

`strtolower($str)`

which I see your using and thats perfect. This is fine and you can stop here.